# Batch file not assigning file contents to variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, windows-7

I am writing this batch file. I need to assign the contents of a temporary file to a variable. I already did it in the same file and it is working so I'm unsure as to why it isn't working.

```
@echo off

rem set Microsoft Windows Version value to variable 
ver > myVersion.txt
set /p  compver = < myVersion.txt
del myVersion.txt

rem set computer hostname value to variable 
hostname > compName.txt
set /p myCompName = < compName.txt
del compName.txt

echo Hello %username%, you are currently logged into %myCompName%.
echo It is %time%, on %date%.
echo You are using a PC that is running %compver%
```

When I run this batch file the hostname does display but the version doesn't.

The result is:

```
Hello John, you are currently logged into JohnDoe.
it is 3:06:04:43, on Tue 12/11/2018
you are using a PC that is running .
```

Comment: Do not put spaces before the `=`-sign: `set /P compver= < myVersion.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are quite complicated I think... You can just use `for /f` to parse the output of the command you want just like the following example:

```bat
@echo off

rem set Microsoft Windows Version value to variable 
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('ver') do set "compver=%%A"

rem set computer hostname value to variable 
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('hostname') do set "myCompName=%%A"

echo Hello %username%, you are currently logged into %myCompName%.
echo It is %time%, on %date%.
echo You are using a PC that is running %compver%
rem pause
```

Use the `delims=` option not to split the output of the command enclosed in `''` symbols.